# Grails shell not functional in Grails 3.0.2?

Tags: shell, grails, grails-3.0

Grails now builds using gradle --which is great-- but a side effect seems to be the shell no longer works? When I run

```
 $ grails shell
```

It doesn't appear to allow me to type any input, and cursor is stuck on grade's building line.

```
Groovy Shell (2.4.3, JVM: 1.8.0_45)
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
groovy:000>
> Building 83% > :shell
```

I've had this problem trying to make interactive groovy scripts that build in gradle - is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grails inherited this [bug](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/641) from springboot. It is now fixed and will be packed in grails 3.03 probably. Till then I would recommend using grails console instead. It will open a swing UI and will have same environment as grails shell.